# C++ Server Pages

Tags: c++, html, scripting

I came across this site a few months ago, but only remembered to download it today. It's called CSP (C++ Server Pages), and it's basically just C++ inside a webpage (like cscript, i think). Anyways: http://www.micronovae.com/

Do any of you have any experience with this? Have you used it on any website you've made/been involved with?

And are there external resources floating around the web that I haven't been able to find yet?

I've tried to search Google for "How to do X in csp" and "How to do Y in C++ Server Pages" ETC, but all I get is just a bunch of results that take me to sites where I can download the product from.

It seems like there's no real community using it, or maybe not many people use it?

Does C++ Server Pages support MySQL usage? I know it supports ODBC (but I don't know how to use that lol), but the cool thing about C++ Server Pages is that you can import any library that C++ has (even third party ones), so maybe I can import the MySQL Connector thing into C++ Server Pages and use mysql that way?

Comment: That is defintely new too me, +1

Comment: I've seen it kicking around for years, but I've never seen / heard of it used much.  There aren't really too many advantages in building a web application in C++.  Unless performance is absolutely critical or you have a site with extreme traffic like facebook most of your bottlenecks will be IO.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote, @Steven. I like rep :) - And yeah, I was so excited to find out about C++ Server Pages. Even if I can't use it for what I need to use it for (mainly MySQL stuff), I'll find a way to use it for something else!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the best c++ web framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework)

Comment: Given the success of hiphop project, I am not surprised to see C++ is going further.

Comment: @user534498, are you referring to the hiphop project movie?

Comment: Yea I like rep too Gotactics WOOT!

Comment: @Closer: I don't believe this one should be considered a duplicate. Since I'm not interested in the frameworks listed on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework - and I have more specific questions. :-)

Comment: If you can use odbc you should be able to connect to mysql.  Odbc is a standard database driver.  The msdn is great reference for all things odbc.  I don't have any experience with server pages though.

Comment: Thank you, @Dan. I'll go read up on ODBC on MSDN.

Comment: Well, the 'IO bottleneck' is really a 'waiting bottleneck' - which is why C++ could be great for it - much less RAM resources consumed at waiting, much faster context switching - it yields much better user/server ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI the [POCO libraries](http://pocoproject.org/) also have C++ server pages: http://pocoproject.org/docs/PageCompilerUserGuide.html

I mention it because CSP seems to have been last updated in 2008.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Pablo! - I just decided before coming back here that I'll probably never use CSP because it requires too much work just to set it all up AND it doesn't work on Windows Vista or Windows 7 (which is what I have). Checking out your link now :)

Comment: could you please be so kind as to inform me how I can get this working on my hosting account? My hosting provider is http://www.winhost.com/ I have read all the POCO Docs, googled, and read the forums, and your links, and cannot find where it says how to get it running on my server. I'm not running this from my own computer, it will be running on a remote server (Win Host). Thanks

Comment: What you get from running the Page Compiler is an executable that should run as its own process. That is, it won't run inside IIS or Apache.I'm not familiar with Winhost, so you're better off asking them directly.